# Python use variable as dict key with equality syntax

Tags: python

I have:

```
dict_ = dict(a="dog")
```

How can I add a variable `BATCH_SIZE = "*batch_size"` to this dictionary?

If I just do:

```
dict_ = dict(a="dog",
BATCH_SIZE=32)
```

If will treat BATCH_SIZE as a string and not a reference. I want it to treat BATCH_SIZE as a variable/reference.

Comment: Use literal instead of function call: `dict_ = {BATCH_SIZE: 32}`

Comment: What do you actually mean by "I want it to treat BATCH_SIZE as a variable/reference"? I suspect what you're looking for is not what wim's comment does - I doubt what you're looking for is something that's actually possible or makes sense for what dicts represent.

Comment: After calling `dict()`, add the key in a separate step: `dict_[BATCH_SIZE] = "whatever"`

Comment: For example, if you had the line `BATCH_SIZE=12` above the construction of your dict, would you want to create the dict `{12: 32}`? That's what wim's comment does (and now John Gordon's comment too).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The aim is to use whatever the name `BATCH_SIZE` is bound to as a key. And this indeed works using @wim's method.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa: That's the interpretation everyone else is taking, but I don't think it's the questioner's intent.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The OP should add the intended result, but I'd assume as the others do that it is `{'a': 'dog', '*batch_size': 32}`.

Comment: @user3180: Also, if you had the line `BATCH_SIZE='foo'` *after* the creation of your dict, what would you want the dict to look like after that line?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Right, that is the other case which is possible. :-)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Yes that's correct

Comment: I was hoping for something that doesn't use the curly brace syntax... I don't like it because I have to add double quotes for all the strings

Comment: I guess I could make a dict with the equal signs syntax and update it with the elements that need variable keys

Comment: The  `dict()` constructor will always interpret the keyword arguments keys as `str` keys for creation of the dict, so there is no way around using a literal, or insertion like `d[key] = value`. Thus, arguably constructing standard dicts using `{}` syntax is preferable over using the `dict()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dict_ = {a: "dog"}
dict_[BATCH_SIZE] = 32
```